# Should I downgrade mu version for emacs mailing?

Tags: emacs, mu, mu4e

I am setting up my new desktop and I get this error message
on emacs when I try to open mu4e:

```
error in process filter: mu4e-error: [mu4e] mu server has version 1.2.0, but we need 1.1.0
error in process filter: [mu4e] mu server has version 1.2.0, but we need 1.1.0
[mu4e] Contacts received: 815
```

Should I downgrade my mu version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem :
I downloaded mu 1-2 source code and replaced my current .emacs.d/lisp/mu4e directory with the new one from the package.